# Using a Column Name in a VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that takes data from the other 52 spreadsheets and totals it.

The columns in the sheet correspond to the names of the other spreadsheets (using dates, i.e., 01/01/2017 column contains data from 01012017 spreadsheet).  If I change the column names to match the spreadsheet names, how do I use them in the VLOOKUP, so I can just copy my formulas and not have to update the formula in each column?

My VLOOKUP formula is this:  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,'12302016'!$A$7:$I$22,9,FALSE),0)

How do I change the '12302016' to use the column name?

[image: Screenshot of my data]

I know that I cannot put 12/30/2016 as my spreadsheet name.

Comment: Have a look on `INDIRECT` function. Probably that's what you need

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of what your data looks like? I'm having trouble understanding what you need from the prompt, but I agree with @MátéJuhász that you'll probably want to use `INDIRECT`

Comment: @MátéJuhász, thank you.  I, also, added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `'12302016'!$A$7:$I$22` use:

`INDIRECT("'"&SUBSTITUTE (TEXT(E$1,"dd/mm/yyyy),"/","")&"'!$A$7:$I$22")`

Where `E$1` is your header.